# How can I get a certain RGB value from a canvas painted with LinearGradientPaint?

Tags: java, colors, gradient, paintcomponent, linear-gradients

I have used the [LinearGradientPaint class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/LinearGradientPaint.html) to draw a rectangle dynamically filled with user-defined colors. This happens by overriding the `paintComponent` method.

Here is how it looks like:

[image: Image of box painted with LinearGradientPaint].

You can see the small thumbs/ handle on top. The user can move these around, delete them, and add new ones. They can also change the color. As a result the user can completely customize how the gradient looks like. This works just fine so far, no issue.

What I need now, and I tried searching for this info, is to get RGB-values *anywhere* on this gradient.

I only know the x-amount of colors that `LinearGradientPaint` uses to generate the gradient. I know at what point (fraction) these colors are located (the number below the gradient box, corresponding with the 'thumbs' on top.

Is there anyway to get the colors in between the RGB-values which are used to generate the gradient? In my example above I mean the darkened red or green areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this really is a linear gradient between `new Color(r1,g1,b1)` and `new Color(r2,g2,b2)`, then the colour at `x`, where `0 <= x <= 1` is

```
new Color((int)(r1*(1-x)+r2*x),(int)(g1*(1-x)+g2*x),(int)(b1*(1-x)+b2*x));
```

Of course, I have no idea whether this is the formula that is actually used inside `LinearGradientPaint` - but it ought to be something equivalent to this.

Comment: It would be ok if this works as a good approximate. It doesn't have to be 100% precise for my purposes.

Comment: Well, give it a try and see how well it works for you.  It will certainly calculate quickly.

Answer (score 1):

A way you might be able to do this, is to create a 1 pixel high `BufferedImage` of the same width of your component, render the gradient to it and simple use something like `BufferedImage#getRGB`.

This will return a `int` packed color value, which you can then use [`Color(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28int%29) to return a `Color` object, which makes it easier to extract the color components of the pixel.

Of course, this would all be easier if you used the `BufferedImage` as your primary output as well, then you would only have to create it once and because you'd be updating the image so it could be rendered to the screen, it would also be up-to-date

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like a good suggestion. I will try this out and accept your answer if it works!